# Rosetta Stone network communication error

Tags: wine

I know there are lots of Rosetta Stone questions, but I've not seen this problem yet.

Everything installed great with wine, appears to functioning well, but I can't get into the actual lessons because when it tries to activate it comes up with an error that reads, "We're unable to communicate with the server right now. Please try again later."

My question is, could this possibly be a wine/ubuntu setting or is it legitimately the Rosetta Stone server?

Comment: Is the error number shown (4118 perhaps?)?

Comment: 5611 actually...

Comment: 5611: Rosetta has this to say about it: http://support.rosettastone.com/en/language-learning/articles/How-do-I-fix-error-5611-on-Version-4-CD-ROM (problem with the learner of a browser setting). Maybe that can help track down your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Rosetta Stone's solution above will NOT fix the issue...

The problem is with the crooks at Microsoft -- they want $$$ for their latest operating system, and have paid off many companies, such as Rosetta Stone, to BLOCK Win-XP in order to force people to upgrade...  Should be illegal, but I digress..

The fix is to go to your unity launcher and search for Wine.  You want the Configure Wine app..  Once it launches, there is a "Windows Version" drop down at the bottom.  Change it to windows 7.

Thats it..  Start Rosetta again and it will work....   Typical results of corporate greed.....